# Fat loss : cut or bulk?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding, burn-fat, cutting, bulking

I'm 1.70m tall and my weight is 73kg.
My fat level is at 23%.
I hit the gym 5/6 times a week and use the push/pull/legs method and eat 1900 calories a day with 35% of my diet based on protein.

I'm looking forward to losing fat while building muscle.
Apparently, there are two methods :

- Caloric deficit : this helps losing fat but not necessarily building muscle. In my case, it works but I lose weight as well which includes muscles.
- Slightly bulking : some advocate that building muscle cannot be without eating over maintenance. Whe I do it, my fat increases as well.

So which method is the best to both burn fat and burn muscle ?

Comment: Asking questions such as "Which method is best" is opinion based, and not a great fit for the stack exchange model. Additionally, this question has been asked and answered quite a few times on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to equally prioritise fat loss and muscle gain is a body recompositions strategy. That means eating calories at your maintenance level so your weight stays the same while training for muscle growth. Essentially, as you put on muscle, you'll be losing losing an equivalent amount of mass as fat. This will optimise muscle gain as much as can be done while removing the risk of further fat gain that comes with a bulk.

If you choose to bulk, depending on the intensity of your training, you may not gain much or any fat but it is highly unlikely you would lose any.

Unless you're so determined to gain strength/muscle mass that you don't care about the possible fat gain, I think the best choice for you would be body recomp.